# How to sort widgets in FLTK for arrow key navigation to work?

Tags: sorting, user-interface, widget, focus, fltk

The FLTK Documentation says:

The arrow, tab, and shift+tab keys "navigate" the selection. Left, right, tab, or shift+tab move to the next or previous widgets in the hierarchy.  **If the navigation does not seem to work you probably need to "Sort" the widgets.**  This is important if you have input fields, as FLTK uses the same rules when using arrow keys to move between input fields.

My project has some following characteristics:

1. Many widgets, created and deleted haphazardly, which makes keeping track of order of creation of widgets difficult (based on which the default navigation works)
2. Widgets are of different type, input, output, buttons, etc.
3. I have have already done Fl::option(Fl::OPTION_ARROW_FOCUS, 1), to enable arrow navigation so that arrow navigation doesn't cause the focus(cursor) to stay stuck in text fields.

What do they mean by "sort the widgets"? How do I sort the widgets so that navigation works intuitively?  Is there any algorithm for this?

Thanks.

Comment: By sorting, they probably mean to (re)create widgets in particular order within a group.

Answer (score 1):

You can do sorting as follows:

```
void User_Group :: SortWidgets()
{
    Fl_Widget   *pt[TOTAL_WIDGETS], *temp;
    int         i, j, TotalNoOfChild = children();

//----------INITIALIZE TO NULL THE CHILD ARRAY *pt[]----------
    for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_WIDGETS; i++)
    pt[i]= NULL;

//----------COPYING CHILDREN FROM THE GROUP INTO POINTER ARRAY *pt[]----------
    for (i = 0; i < TotalNoOfChild; i++)
    pt[i]= (child(i));

//----------REMOVING CHILDREN FROM CHILDREN FROM THE GROUP----------
    while (children() > 0)
    remove(0);

//----------SORTING CHILD ARRAY *pt[] ACCORDING TO CO-ORDINATES----------
    for (i = 0; i < TotalNoOfChild + 1; i++)
    {
    for (j = i + 1; j < TotalNoOfChild; j++)
    {
        if ((pt[i]->y()) > (pt[j]->y()))
        {
            temp=pt[i];
            pt[i]=pt[j];
            pt[j]=temp;
        }
    }
    }

for (i = 0; i < TotalNoOfChild + 1; i++)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < TotalNoOfChild; j++)
    {
        if (((pt[i]->x())>(pt[j]->x())) && ((pt[i]->y()) >= (pt[j]->y())))
        {
            temp=pt[i];
            pt[i]=pt[j];
            pt[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}

/*
 //----------ALTERNATE SORTING----------
for (i = 0; i < TotalNoOfChild + 1; i++)
{
    for (j = i+1; j < TotalNoOfChild; j++)
    {
      if (((pt[i]->y())*1000+(pt[i]->x()))>((pt[j]->y())*1000+(pt[j]->x())))
      {
            temp=pt[i];
            pt[i]=pt[j];
            pt[j]=temp;
      }
    }
}
*/

//----------RE-ADDING CHILDREN INTO THE GROUP----------
for (i = 0; i < TotalNoOfChild; i++)
    add(pt[i]);
```

}